# Hazelcast Clustering TCP-IP based

Tags: java, tcp, hazelcast

I am using Hazecast discovery based on TCP IP. (3.7 version)  When you create instances , however , it creates the processes on the same machine :

The configuration is :

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <members>myhost1,myhost2</members>                
</tcp-ip>
```

(* Also probed to configure member by member into the xml)

Resulting logs:

```
Members [2] {
                Member [myhost1]:5701 - a5f40be8-62ae-5078-9ce4-86a7e5075224
                Member [myhost1]:5702 - 9aca0907-46d8-546d-b8db-28a58b77274f
}
```

We just want to have ONE HAZELCAST instance per machine.....  Using multicast you just get :

```
Members [2] {
                Member [myhost1]:5701 - b5f40be9-62ae-6008-9ce4-96a7e5075224
                Member [myhost2]:5701 - 0bcad9f7-46d8-506b-a8db-28b58b07274f
}
```

Anything wrong in the configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you need one instance per machine just start hazelcast on each one using stahdard configuration. Note that all machines should be located at the same subnet (must be discoverable by broadcast).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<port auto-increment="false">5701</port>
```

So you have

```
<network>
 <port auto-increment="false">5701</port>
 <join>
  <multicast enabled="false">
  <tcp-ip enabled="true">
   ...
```

Comment: That's what you wanted isn't it ? If TCP is only allowed to use one port then you can only run one instance per machine